# Require users to sign up or login to upvote or downvote review items on a user-generated content site?

Tags: registration, signup-signon, ratings, voting

I'm trying to get more people to rate products on a video game ratings and review website. Will allowing non registered users to upvote/downvote the reviews increase engagement and sign ups?
in other words, would it be better if non-logged in users can upvote/downvote already written reviews by registered users?

Comment: This really depends on how you define your ratings and reviews.  Allowing anyone to up/down vote can result in arbitrary voting thus reduce the helpfulness of the vote.  If you require users to sign in/up before voting, that's a major barrier against engagement.  Pros and cons for both and it's really up to you to decide if the integrity of the vote is more or less important than increasing user engagement.

Comment: yes that makes sense but i'm trying to increase engagement for passive users while simultaneously signing up the more serious users who want to engage further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may indeed get more interactions, but conversions could easily go either way... why should I sign up if I can vote anyway?

I would be far more concerned with vote manipulation and would suggest the risks of that would outweigh any benefits.

You could allow votes and add them to a "pending" list and apply them when the user signs up (based on a cookie).

Personally I would look to make sign up  following a click to vote as simple as possible and require it prior to applying the vote. Most people are happy to sign up with a Facebook or Google Id. If you don't ask for any extra fields or access your conversion rate should be high.

This brings me to my final point. You could try to track conversion rate based on different approaches and keep the method that works best. You also need to consider how to encourage shares... again integration with social networks can help there too.

Comment: that's a good idea ala cookie but the difference would be signing up allows you to write a comment(140character review) and voting just lets you vote up or down that comment

Comment: Hi, I guess I was destined for a role in security because gaming rule systems has long been a pastime of mine...from exams to review sites. To some extent it depends on the motivation of your users but I suspect many would write a review, log out and vote it up. Possibly repeatedly, from several computers, over a period of time...

Comment: good point andy - i wonder how many people would be motivated to do that but probably should be safe than sorry then